# Is this the same place referred in these Scriptures? If so, what is its significance?

Tags: jesus, moses, gospels, 2-peter, elijah

Exodus 19:20 :- “Then the Lord came down upon Mount Sinai, on the top of the mountain. And the Lord called Moses to the top of the mountain, and Moses went up.”

Matthew 17:1:- “Now after six days Jesus took Peter, James, and John his brother, led them up on a high mountain by themselves; …”

Mark 9:2:- “Now after six days Jesus took Peter, James, and John, and led them up on a high mountain apart by themselves; and He was transfigured before them.”

Luke 9:28:- “Now it came to pass, about eight days after these sayings, that He took Peter, John, and James and went up on the mountain to pray.”

2Peter 1:18:- “And we heard this voice which came from heaven when we were with Him on the holy mountain.”

Please note the presence of Moses and Elijah in Matthew 17:3; Mark 9:4; and Luke 9:30-31.

Comment: I’m pretty sure Mt. Sinai in Exodus 19:20 is in Arabia or Egypt, not in Israel.

Comment: I’m stunned by the mind blowing settings, the events that took place within the contexts of these texts, and the everlasting truth in these texts of the Scripture.

Answer (score 4):

The general, but far from certain consensus is that Jesus' mountain of transfiguration was Mt Tabor as expressed by Ellicott:

> **Into an high mountain**.—A tradition of uncertain date fixes on Tabor as the scene of the Transfiguration, but this was probably due
> to the conspicuous position of that mountain, as it rises abruptly
> from the plain of Esdraelon. The Gospel narratives leave the locality
> altogether uncertain, but as Cæsarea Philippi was the last place
> mentioned, and a journey through Galilee follows (Mark 9:30), it is
> more probable that the scene is to be found on one of the heights of
> Hermon. Tabor, it may be added, was crowned with a fortress, which at
> this time was likely to be occupied, and this is obviously
> inconsistent with the solitude which the narrative implies.

However, this is uncertain; what we can be reasonably confident about is that the mountain was somewhere in Israel.  This is over 600 km from Mt Sinai in Arabia.

Therefore, the mount of transfiguration was not Mt Sinai.

Comment: It seems significant that references to "a high mountain" are not named. High mountains have names. Peter considered the mount of transfiguration a "holy mountain," but again this holy mountain is not named by him. Most assuredly if the mount of transfiguration were identified, there would be three large structures on it now, if not several multiples of three. Perhaps, we're not supposed to develop an "edifice complex." ;-)